# ¿Como crear un archivo de redireccion con destinos diferentes en PHP?

Tags: php, php5, redirección

Me explico, uso publicidad en mi pagina web. pero tengo 2 proveedores diferentes por cada publicidad, entonces lo que quiero es que cuando un usuario le de click en el barner, lo lleve a un archivo PHP que contenga los 2 destinos, si el usuario hace click la primera vez, que lo lleve al primero, si lo hace por una segunda vez que lo lleve al segundo, si lo hace por una tercera vez, entonces que empiece otra vez con el primero. que sea un ciclo. o en su defecto, que sea por segundos, es decir que el PHP, tenga una secuencia que cada tantos segundos, cambie entre 2 destinos diferentes. Tengo esto hasta ahora:

```
            if(){ 
                header ('Location: http://www.misitio1.com'); 

            }else{ 

                header ('Location: http://www.misitio2.com'); 
            }
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Te recomendaría colocar el código con lo que has intentado hasta ahora para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Un saludo

Comment: Esto es relativamente fácil.  Sólo debes crear una variable de session o cookie para el usuario, con la que  poder hacer un condicional y decidir a donde Redireccionar al usuario. O si lo haces con tiempo, podrías hacer un condicional para que los minutos o segundos pares se redirección a un sitio y los impares a otro... muestranos que has intentado.

Comment: `if(){ 
                        header ('Location: http://www.misitio1.com'); 

                    }else{ 
                         
                        header ('Location: http://www.misitio2.com'); 
                    }` Tengo eso, ¿Como le agregaria lo de los minutos o segundos pares e impares en el condicional?

Comment: Como te han comentado lo de los segundos impares lo podrias hacer con `date("s")` (esto te devuelve los segundos actuales) y en tu `if` compruebas si es par o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te expuse en el comentario, por ejemplo puedes comprobar si el segundo o minuto es par o impar, o utilizar cualquier otra formula con numeros pseudo-aleatorios por ejemplo.

Ejemplos:

Puedes optener un numero variable con alguna de las siguientes formas:

```
// minutos
$numero = date('i');
// segundos
$numero = date('s');
// numeros pseudo-aleatorios
$numero = mt_rand();
```

Luego simplemente compruebas si es par o impar

```
if($numero%2==0){
    // PAR
    header ('Location: http://www.misitio1.com'); 
}else{ 
    // IMPAR
    header ('Location: http://www.misitio2.com'); 
}
```

Siguiendo la misma fórmula podemos crear un rango de segundos, de 0 a 30 a un sitio, de 31 a 60 otro, ejemplo:

```
if(date('s') <= 30){
    // segundo menor o igual a 30
    header ('Location: http://www.misitio1.com'); 
}else{ 
    // segundo mayor a 30
    header ('Location: http://www.misitio2.com'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo la idea de Xerif , solo que lo lo haría con un contador almacenado en la session, ya que con el tiempo se puede repetir la redirección.

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['clicks'])) { 
    $_SESSION['clicks'] = 0;
}
$clicks = $_SESSION['clicks'];

$_SESSION['clicks'] = $clicks + 1;

if ($clicks % 2 == 0) {
    header ('Location: http://www.misitio1.com'); 
}else{
     header ('Location: http://www.misitio2.com');  
}
```